# How to run sequence over List[F[G[A]]] to get F[G[List[A]]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

Is it possible to transform a `List[F[G[A]]]` into `F[G[List[A]]]` nicely?

I can do this in Scalaz the following way:

```
val x: List[Future[Option[Int]]] = ???
val transformed: Future[Option[List[Int]]] = x.sequenceU.map(_.sequenceU)
```

I'm just wondering if there's a nicer way to do this rather than `.sequenceU.map(_.sequenceU)` Perhaps using a monad transformer? I did attempt this, without much luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monad transformers are the way to go if you want to avoid the nested sequencing. In this case you want an `OptionT[Future, A]` (which is equivalent to `Future[Option[A]]`):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

val xs = List(OptionT(Future(some(1))), OptionT(Future(some(2))))
val ys = OptionT(Future(none[Int])) :: xs

val sequencedXs: Future[Option[List[Int]]] = xs.sequenceU.run
val sequencedYs: Future[Option[List[Int]]] = ys.sequenceU.run
```

And then:

```
scala> sequencedXs.foreach(println)
Some(List(1, 2))

scala> sequencedYs.foreach(println)
None
```

As expected.

Comment: It's quite obvious when you think about it, really :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that while a monad transformer is great here, I can take advantage that applicatives compose:

```
def transform[F[_], G[_], A](list: List[F[G[A]]])(implicit af: Applicative[F], ao: Applicative[G]): F[G[List[A]]] = {
  type λ[α] = F[G[α]]
  implicit val applicative: Applicative[λ] = af compose ao
  list.sequence[λ, A]
}
val lfo:    List[Future[Option[Int]]] = List(Future(1.some), Future(2.some))
val future: Future[Option[List[Int]]] = transform(lfo)
```

And then:

```
scala> future.foreach(println)
Some(List(1, 2))
```

Comment: Which, of course, Lars suggested at the time, but it didn't click for me then. https://twitter.com/larsr_h/status/517997668866723840